# Occasional exception on startup with SignalR and ASP.NET MVC 3 on IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm writing an internal web app for our server software that uses ASP.NET MVC 3 and SignalR 0.5.2.  We're occasionally seeing the following exception on startup:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
   at SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.Infrastructure.AspNetAssemblyLocator.GetAssemblies()
   at SignalR.Hubs.ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider.BuildHubsCache()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at SignalR.Hubs.ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider.TryGetHub(String hubName, HubDescriptor& descriptor)
   at SignalR.Hubs.DefaultHubManager.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetHub>b__0(IHubDescriptorProvider p)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at SignalR.Hubs.DefaultHubManager.GetHub(String hubName)
   at SignalR.Hubs.HubManagerExtensions.EnsureHub(IHubManager hubManager, String hubName)
   at SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.GetSignals(ClientHubInfo hubInfo, String connectionId)
   at SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass23.<CreateConnection>b__22(ClientHubInfo info)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__71`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.UnionWith(IEnumerable`1 other)
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at SignalR.Connection..ctor(IMessageBus messageBus, IJsonSerializer jsonSerializer, String baseSignal, String connectionId, IEnumerable`1 signals, IEnumerable`1 groups, ITraceManager traceManager)
   at SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.CreateConnection(String connectionId, IEnumerable`1 groups, IRequest request)
   at SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context)
   at SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context)
   at SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContextBase context)
   at SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I suspect this happens because there is a browser open while we're restarting IIS Express and it's making a request (via the SignalR javascript) at the exact moment between when the hub routes are mapped and the initialization finishes.  I could be entirely wrong about the cause, we have unfortunately not been able to reproduce this reliably and this is my first ASP.NET project so I'm pretty lost as to what could be happening.

This is our NinjectWebCommon.cs file in the App_Start folder:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WebStatusClient.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(WebStatusClient.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace WebStatusClient.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;
    using SignalR.Infrastructure;
    using SignalR.Ninject;
    using SignalR;
    using System.Web.Routing;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        public static StandardKernel Kernel { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);

            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            Kernel = new StandardKernel();
            Kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            Kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(Kernel);
            return Kernel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<Impl.StatusForwarder>()
                .To<Impl.StatusForwarder>()
                .InSingletonScope();

            kernel.Bind<StatusInterfaceClient.IStatusNotificationTarget>()
                .ToMethod(context => context.Kernel.Get<Impl.StatusForwarder>());

            // Set the SignalR dependency injector.
            SignalR.GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new SignalR.Ninject.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

            // Force the creation of the status manager.
            Impl.StatusInterfaceManager.Initialize();
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions for figuring out what could be going wrong?  Should I be mapping the hubs later in the initialization process?

Comment: Can you try to pregenerate the hubs.js file by using hubify.exe (look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/06/10/signalr-0-5-1-released.aspx) for details) and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: That should actually be unrelated as your hubs.js file is already loaded in the browser, sorry.

Comment: I am calling it in the Start() method inside of the NinjectWebCommon static class.  I posted the contents of App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs so you should be able to see it in context.  This is the only file in the App_Start folder.